# Getting Error in simple delete query in MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am getting very strange issue when I am trying to delete record from a table using below query:

```
delete from `user_join_groups` where `group_id` = 1 and `user_id` = 217;
```

Below is the error that Mysql is throwing:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.user_id' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `user_join_groups` where `group_id` = 1 and `user_id` = 217)  
//"Test" is my database name
```

I am using Laravel framework for my project where I am running above query. Below is the laravel code to that generate above mysql query for deletion:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('user_join_groups')
     ->where('group_id', $group_id)
     ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->delete();
```

I have also attached the screenshot of error that laravel is throwing. In screenshot, laravel is also showing things related to migration but I am not sure why I am getting this.

[image]

Apart from Laravel, I have also tried to delete same record from PHPMYADMIN and here I am getting same erorr.

[image]

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with above query and why I am getting this error?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's not how Eloquent works. To delete a relation you have to use a dedicated method, not a query builder

Comment: "Test" can't be your database name because from the error message above, it says "Table 'test.user_id' doesn't exist so it has to be a table. Find out what your database name is and make sure you issue the command to use the database first ("use <db_name>"). Also do you have the two tables "user_join_groups" and "test" in your database? Also try prefixing your database name and table name to your fields e.g. delete from "db.test.user_join_groups" where "db.test.group_id" = 1 and "db.test.user_id" = 217;

Comment: From the name alone `user_join_groups` sounds like a pivot table. In Laravel you would not normally manually delete records from pivot tables, you delete the relation.  Laravel is probably trying to delete the corresponding user and group records but getting messed up.

Comment: @Ezani my database is not named as "test". we have real database name but due to privacy issue, I have replaced actual database name with "test". And I am using laravel to delete records. So, laravel automatically uses database name and prefix it with table name automatically. Please check my screenshot

Comment: You have several tables with foreign key constraints between them. The DB is enforcing integrity by making sure those related records exist, or are deleted, when you manually go in adding/deleting records.  As already pointed out several times, Laravel manages the pivot table for you and you shouldn't be manually deleting records from it.  Check the docs for [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) relationships, [attaching/detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: @Don'tPanic Currently, I don't have any foriegn key relationship on any table and also tried with laravel's deattach() function to remove record. But still getting same error. And I have noticed that, it is coming when I delete record of user id = 1

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your table do not exist .Make sure you created the model for table with proper entries and then run "php artisan migrate" . n